# How to change the zoom factor to only zoom OUT on Ken Burns effect?

Tags: javascript, jquery, canvas, zooming

I am helping a friend with a website, and he is using the **Ken Burns Effect with Javascript and Canvas** from this site  https://www.willmcgugan.com/blog/tech/post/ken-burns-effect-with-javascript-and-canvas/
for a slide-show. It works perfectly, but he would like to change the zoom effect to where all of the images zoom OUT, instead of alternating between zooming in and out.

After about a week of "scrambling" the code unsuccessfully, he posted a question about it on the site.   The reply he received was (quote) "*That's definitely possible, with a few tweaks of the code. Sorry, no time to give you guidance at the moment, but it shouldn't be all that difficult*" (end quote).

I can't seem to figure it out either, so I'm hoping that someone here may be of help. Below is the code as posted on the willmcgugan.com website. Any help on how to change the zoom effect would be greatly appreciated.

```
(function($){

    $.fn.kenburns = function(options) {

        var $canvas = $(this);
        var ctx = this[0].getContext('2d');
        var start_time = null;
        var width = $canvas.width();
        var height = $canvas.height();

        var image_paths = options.images;
        var display_time = options.display_time || 7000;
        var fade_time = Math.min(display_time / 2, options.fade_time || 1000);
        var solid_time = display_time - (fade_time * 2);
        var fade_ratio = fade_time - display_time
        var frames_per_second = options.frames_per_second || 30;
        var frame_time = (1 / frames_per_second) * 1000;
        var zoom_level = 1 / (options.zoom || 2);
        var clear_color = options.background_color || '#000000';

        var images = [];
        $(image_paths).each(function(i, image_path){
            images.push({path:image_path,
                         initialized:false,
                         loaded:false});
        });
        function get_time() {
            var d = new Date();
            return d.getTime() - start_time;
        }

        function interpolate_point(x1, y1, x2, y2, i) {
            // Finds a point between two other points
            return  {x: x1 + (x2 - x1) * i,
                     y: y1 + (y2 - y1) * i}
        }

        function interpolate_rect(r1, r2, i) {
            // Blend one rect in to another
            var p1 = interpolate_point(r1[0], r1[1], r2[0], r2[1], i);
            var p2 = interpolate_point(r1[2], r1[3], r2[2], r2[3], i);
            return [p1.x, p1.y, p2.x, p2.y];
        }

        function scale_rect(r, scale) {
            // Scale a rect around its center
            var w = r[2] - r[0];
            var h = r[3] - r[1];
            var cx = (r[2] + r[0]) / 2;
            var cy = (r[3] + r[1]) / 2;
            var scalew = w * scale;
            var scaleh = h * scale;
            return [cx - scalew/2,
                    cy - scaleh/2,
                    cx + scalew/2,
                    cy + scaleh/2];
        }

        function fit(src_w, src_h, dst_w, dst_h) {
            // Finds the best-fit rect so that the destination can be covered
            var src_a = src_w / src_h;
            var dst_a = dst_w / dst_h;
            var w = src_h * dst_a;
            var h = src_h;
            if (w > src_w)
            {
                var w = src_w;
                var h = src_w / dst_a;
            }
            var x = (src_w - w) / 2;
            var y = (src_h - h) / 2;
            return [x, y, x+w, y+h];
        }

        function get_image_info(image_index, load_callback) {
            // Gets information structure for a given index
            // Also loads the image asynchronously, if required
            var image_info = images[image_index];
            if (!image_info.initialized) {
                var image = new Image();
                image_info.image = image;
                image_info.loaded = false;
                image.onload = function(){
                    image_info.loaded = true;
                    var iw = image.width;
                    var ih = image.height;

                    var r1 = fit(iw, ih, width, height);;
                    var r2 = scale_rect(r1, zoom_level);

                    var align_x = Math.floor(Math.random() * 3) - 1;
                    var align_y = Math.floor(Math.random() * 3) - 1;
                    align_x /= 2;
                    align_y /= 2;

                    var x = r2[0];
                    r2[0] += x * align_x;
                    r2[2] += x * align_x;

                    var y = r2[1];
                    r2[1] += y * align_y;
                    r2[3] += y * align_y;

                    if (image_index % 2) {
                        image_info.r1 = r1;
                        image_info.r2 = r2;
                    }
                    else {
                        image_info.r1 = r2;
                        image_info.r2 = r1;
                    }

                    if(load_callback) {
                        load_callback();
                    }

                }
                image_info.initialized = true;
                image.src = image_info.path;
            }
            return image_info;
        }

        function render_image(image_index, anim, fade) {
            // Renders a frame of the effect
            if (anim > 1) {
                return;
            }
            var image_info = get_image_info(image_index);
            if (image_info.loaded) {
                var r = interpolate_rect(image_info.r1, image_info.r2, anim);
                var transparency = Math.min(1, fade);

                if (transparency > 0) {
                    ctx.save();
                    ctx.globalAlpha = Math.min(1, transparency);
                    ctx.drawImage(image_info.image, r[0], r[1], r[2] - r[0], r[3] - r[1], 0, 0, width, height);
                    ctx.restore();
                }
            }
        }

        function clear() {
            // Clear the canvas
            ctx.save();
            ctx.globalAlpha = 1;
            ctx.fillStyle = clear_color;
            ctx.fillRect(0, 0, ctx.canvas.width, ctx.canvas.height);
            ctx.restore();
        }

        function update() {
            // Render the next frame
            var update_time = get_time();

            var top_frame = Math.floor(update_time / (display_time - fade_time));
            var frame_start_time = top_frame * (display_time - fade_time);
            var time_passed = update_time - frame_start_time;

            function wrap_index(i) {
                return (i + images.length) % images.length;
            }

            if (time_passed < fade_time)
            {
                var bottom_frame = top_frame - 1;
                var bottom_frame_start_time = frame_start_time - display_time + fade_time;
                var bottom_time_passed = update_time - bottom_frame_start_time;
                if (update_time < fade_time) {
                    clear();
                } else {
                    render_image(wrap_index(bottom_frame), bottom_time_passed / display_time, 1);
                }
            }

            render_image(wrap_index(top_frame), time_passed / display_time, time_passed / fade_time);

            if (options.post_render_callback) {
                options.post_render_callback($canvas, ctx);
            }

            // Pre-load the next image in the sequence, so it has loaded
            // by the time we get to it
            var preload_image = wrap_index(top_frame + 1);
            get_image_info(preload_image);
        }

        // Pre-load the first two images then start a timer
        get_image_info(0, function(){
            get_image_info(1, function(){
                start_time = get_time();
                setInterval(update, frame_time);
            })
        });

    };

})( jQuery );
```

Comment: Can you add a fiddle?

Comment: Not sure why, but I can't seem to get it to work in a jsfiddle. However, there is a working example with the full code here http://www.nightwingsgraphics.com/images/kenburnstest.html

Comment: Update: I managed to get a working example in Codepen here http://codepen.io/Mountaingal/pen/zBZzXk  but nothing is showing up in the jsfiddle  https://jsfiddle.net/w6fsc7uf/  even though it's the exact same code (copied & pasted). What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The Codepen works great. See my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the simplest solution, I forked and modified your Codepen here:

http://codepen.io/jjwilly16/pen/NAovkp?editors=1010

I just removed a conditional that controls whether the zoom is moving out or in.

```
if (image_index % 2) {
    image_info.r1 = r1;
    image_info.r2 = r2;
}
else {
    image_info.r1 = r2;
    image_info.r2 = r1;
}
```

Changed to:

```
image_info.r1 = r2;
image_info.r2 = r1;
```

Now it only zooms out :)